# How can i pass string "image0" through this intent in same activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

When i pass string through intent i it gives null pointer exception

```
09-10 12:26:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(28149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/17249 typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }} to activity {com.al.collage/com.al.collage.Collage2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
i.putExtra("image", "image0");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(image0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```